# Composing multipart/form-data with file only using vanilla node.js

Tags: node.js, form-data, zapier

"Code by Zapier" doesn't allow loading npm modules and vanilla node.js doesn't include FormData, it's provided as module "form-data".

Is there another way to compose a multipart/form-data message containing a (binary) file as form part using only vanilla node.js?

Answer (score 0):

While this likely isn't convenient in `Code by Zapier`, you can use the [Zapier Developer Platform](https://platform.zapier.com/) for this. There's even a specific `FormData` example [here](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform/blob/ef40c2260ef9613ce9f7eec6249befcc60dd9abc/example-apps/files/creates/uploadFile_v10.js#L12-L34).

To use it, do the following:

1. Install the CLI ([docs](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform/blob/master/packages/cli/README.md#quick-setup-guide))
2. Run `zapier init --template files my-app`
3. `cd my-app && npm install`

The example app has a create file action, which you'll be able to use in conjunction with any other Zapier apps. You can now remove any bits you don't  need and take it from there!

Comment: I'm aware of this possibility, but I was explicitly asking if it's possible without loading npm modules. Can a message body be composed that mingles the strings of the form part header with the binary data of the file as content of the form part?

Comment: I'm not sure. But, npm packages are (eventually) just vanilla JS, so you could try reading that package and seeing how it handles it.